# Blazor real email confirm by string variable email confirm = false finest work I can’t catch the email

Tags: blazor

I wanted to to the same thing send a email msg but the difference here is whithout a button n it will be in the part of register page by modifying the method sendemailasync n then receive the link on gmail or another email service some one knows how to do that?????? Please   I’m creating a ticket project service

Solve the problem with a real email sender they use sender grid but I want to try with other

Comment: Read the MSDN tutorial they explain the confirm link is only there for development and there is a guide to set up email to go through the confirm process. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: I dont have set my send grid to full so there another way to send a email msg with blazor server if urs know let me know I will appreciate it so much

Comment: Please be more clear about your issue. What do you want to achive exactly? Perhaps provide some code of your app.

Comment: this a shotcut of my code in Blazor Server

Comment: i put the code below please check?

Answer (score 0):

this a shotcut of my code in Blazor Server
i dont have created a Emailsender and even an Interface of if it i am making use of this and no SendGrid:

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;

And than from this i send my msg  is that posible with ?

```
    public async Task SendEmailAsync(string toEmail, string subject, string 
     message)
    {
        MailMessage messagee = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        messagee.From = new MailAddress(_mailConfig.From);
        messagee.To.Add(new MailAddress(toEmail));
        messagee.Subject = subject;
        messagee.IsBodyHtml = true;
        messagee.Body = message;
        smtp.Port = _mailConfig.Port;
        smtp.Host = _mailConfig.SmtpServer;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_mailConfig.UserName, 
        _mailConfig.Password);
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        await smtp.SendMailAsync(messagee);
    }         





    public class EmailConfiguration
    {
        public string From { get; set; }
        public string SmtpServer { get; set; }
        public int Port { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SmtpException: Syntax error, command unrecognized. The server response was:
System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection+ConnectAndHandshakeAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)

Comment: System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection+ConnectAndHandshakeAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.EndGetConnection(IAsyncResult result)
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult result)
BlazorApp1Server.Services.EmailSender.SendEmailAsync(string toEmail, string subject, string message) in EmailSender.cs
+
            await smtp.SendMailAsync(messagee);
BlazorApp1Server.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.RegisterModel.OnPostAsync(string returnUrl) in Register.cshtml.cs
+
                    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",

Comment: Where are the exceptions happening?  these would be better as part of the question body. Also, how is this an answer? If there are exceptions... This seems not to be an answer.